# Microsoft Access: How to do IF in Calculated Field Expression?

Tags: ms-access, vba, calculated-columns

I want my calculated field to have a conditional value like this:
if fieldA is 0 then set fieldC to 0
else field C = fieldB / fieldA

How do I do this? Thanks.

And while you are at it, how do I do this in an Access VBA routine so that I can keep on revising my conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a table definition: not possible.

As a query:

```
SELECT
  IIF(FieldA = 0; 0; FieldB / FieldA) AS FieldC
FROM
  ATableWithFieldAAndFieldB
```

As SQL text in VBA: replace the ; with ,

Answer (score 2):

You can add a procedure like this to your module code...

```
Public Function CalculateFieldC(ByVal fieldA as Long, ByVal fieldB as Long) as Single
  If fieldA = 0 Then
    CalculateFieldC = 0
  Else: CalculateFieldC = fieldB / fieldA
  End If
End Function
```

Then call it from an SQL statement; for example:

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, CaculateFieldC(fieldA, fieldB) AS fieldC
FROM aTableWithFieldAandFieldB;
```

Comment: Sloppy code: the Variant type should be declared for both the parameters and the function return. The return type in particular can noticeably improve Jet/ACE's optimization of a SQL WHERE clause that uses this function.

Comment: I omitted the datatype declarations because I assumed it was implicit that the person who posed the question should be the one to select the appropriate variable type(s) for the procedure inputs and output.

Comment: With regard to declaring both arguments and the function return as variants, I don't really see how that would be an improvement... I thought that in all versions of VB & VBA, omission of the As Type clause automatically results in the Variant data type being assigned to the variable.

That being said, I do agree that Variants should be avoided wherever possible, given the larger memory requirement and increased processing times associated with their use. I typically only declare variants when I want to handle Nulls, or when I need to be able to test if an argument is missing.

Comment: Yes, they will be variants by default, but I don't believe in relying on implicit typing. The parameter arguments are less important than the return type, as the return type can change the way the query compiler optimizes the query. If it knows the result can be NULL, then it can be optimized to use the index in a particular way, whereas if it doesn't know what the return type is, it has less information to go on. I know for a fact that omitting the return type on functions used in the WHERE clause of queries makes them much less efficient in some cases.